# ¿Cómo reagrupo categorías siguiendo una condición?

Tags: r, group-by, r-dplyr

Tengo el siguiente df del que debo agrupar y asignar un número secuencial a la combinación `ID_sitio` y `fecha`, para lo que he utilizado el script que aparece líneas más abajo.

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID_Sitio" = c("ES022", "ES023", "ES024", "ES022", "ES023", "ES024"),
              ID_Individuo = c("001", "002", "005", "011", "022", "055"),
              fecha = c("01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001", "01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001"),
              stringsAsFactors = F)


ID_Sitio     ID_Individuo    fecha           
ES022        001             01-01-2001
ES023        002             02-01-2001
ES024        005             03-01-2001
ES022        011             01-01-2001
ES023        022             02-01-2001
ES024        055             03-01-2001

library(tidyverse)

# Generamos un tabla con los grupos y
# un id numérico para cada uno
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID_Sitio, fecha) %>% 
    summarize((n)) %>%
    rowid_to_column("grupo") -> grupos

# Combinamos el df original con el de los grupos
df1 %>%
    left_join(grupos)

  ID_Sitio ID_Individuo      fecha grupo   n
1    ES022          001 01-01-2001     1   2
2    ES023          002 02-01-2001     2   2
3    ES024          005 03-01-2001     3   2
4    ES022          011 01-01-2001     1   2
5    ES023          022 02-01-2001     2   2
6    ES024          055 03-01-2001     3   2
```

Suponiendo que tengo un número de observaciones por grupo mayor a 2

```
7    ES032          055 03-01-2012     4  25
8    ES042          055 05-01-2012     4  150
9    ES082          055 12-01-2012     4  250
```

Lo que debo hacer es tomar esos grupos con un número de observaciones <=10 y redistribuirlos en cualquier otra categoría que tenga más de 10 observaciones.

He pensado hacerlo

`df1$grupo2<-ifelse(freq<=10, grupo+1, grupo)` pero el problema es que no siempre sumándole 1 a "grupo", tendré un grupo con `freq>1`... Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Y luego de redistribuir los grupos, debo volverlos a enumerar, pero eso será tan sencillo como aplicar nuevamente el `group_by`.

Comment: Y tampoco puedes estar segura que `grupo + 1` te va a caer en un grupo con más de 10 observaciones. ¿Y de que forma quieres distribuir las observaciones?.  Es decir tienes un grupo con 2 observaciones y dos grupos con 30, y con 11, ¿Cómo esperas distribuir esas 2 observaciones? ¿de manera sencilla, una a cada uno de los dos grupos con más de 10? ¿De forma ponderada a la cantidad de observaciones de los grupos de más de 10, tipo los esquemas de asignación de bancas por votos en los sistemas electorales? ¿Al azar?

Comment: Debo distribuir las observaciones de tal forma que si n<=10, las pase a cualquier grupo siempre y cuando sea del mismo año.

Comment: la respuesta que ya te dí, no tiene contemplado tu último comentario: _ siempre y cuando sea del mismo año_, voy a tratar de agregar esto último

Comment: Siento retomar y puntualizar lo que necesitaba con tanto retraso. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: edité mi respuesta para ajustarla a tu último comentario. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a proponerte un esquema de distribución proporcional a la cantidad de observaciones de cada grupo, para no pensar mucho, vamos a usar un esquema del tipo [D´Hondt](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_d%27Hondt), que es un esquema electoral de distribución de los votos que no alcanzan el total mínimo para cubrir una banca. Veamos un caso particular de ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame("ID_Sitio" = c("ES022", "ES023", "ES024", "ES022", "ES023", "ES024"),
                  ID_Individuo = c("001", "002", "005", "011", "022", "055"),
                  fecha = c("01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001", "01-01-2002", "02-01-2002", "03-01-2002"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

set.seed(2019)
df1 <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1), 50, replace = TRUE, prob=c(.3, .1, .1, .1, .1, .3)), ]
```

Primero construimos un nuevo `data.frame` con los datos de interes para el proceso

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(year=as.numeric(str_split(df1$fecha,'-', simplify = T)[,3])) %>% 
    group_by(ID_Sitio,year,fecha) %>% 
    summarize(n=n()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(grupo=row_number(), n_grupo=grupo) %>% 
    left_join(df1, by=c("ID_Sitio", "year", "fecha")) %>% 
    select(ID_Sitio,ID_Individuo, year,fecha, n, grupo, n_grupo) %>% 
    arrange(year,desc(n))  -> df2     

head(df2,12)

# A tibble: 12 x 7
   ID_Sitio ID_Individuo  year fecha          n grupo n_grupo
   <chr>    <chr>        <dbl> <chr>      <int> <int>   <int>
 1 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 2 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 3 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 4 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 5 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 6 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 7 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 8 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
 9 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
10 ES022    001           2001 01-01-2001    10     1       1
11 ES024    005           2001 03-01-2001     9     5       5
12 ES024    005           2001 03-01-2001     9     5       5
```

En este nuevo `df2` tenemos los datos originales pero además, `year`, ya que la asignación a cada grupo siempre es dentro del mismo año, `n` que es la cantidad de observaciones para el grupo de cada fila, `grupo` que es un numerador de cada uno de estos y `n_grupo` que va a representar luego la distribución final de grupos.

Usaremos el esquema [D´Hondt](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_d%27Hondt), para asignar las observaciones de aquellos grupos que no cumplan con el mínimo (perdedores) a los grupos que si lo hacen (vencedores) esto siempre por cada año, ya que una observación de un año solo se deberá asignarse a un grupo de ese mismo año

Hay paquetería en R que contemplan varios algoritmos electorales, por ejemplo: [`electoral`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/electoral/electoral.pdf), pero lo cierto que tampoco es tan complejo de implementar, voy a adaptar [este](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2009-February/380089.html) código:

```
dHondt <- function( candidates, votes, seats ){

    tmp <- data.frame(
        candidates = rep( candidates, each = seats ),
        scores     = as.vector(sapply( votes, function(x) x /
                                           1:seats ))
    )
    tmp$candidates[order( - tmp$scores )] [1:seats]
}
```

El proceso es un poco más complejo debido a que como mencionábamos es por año:

```
final <- data.frame()
for (y in unique(df2$year)) {

    vencedores <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(n>=10, year==y)
    perdedores <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(n<10, year==y)

    df2 %>% 
        filter(year==y) %>% 
        mutate(n_grupo = ifelse(n<10, 
                                dHondt(vencedores$grupo, vencedores$n, sum(perdedores$n)), 
                                grupo)
        ) %>% 
        bind_rows(final) -> final
}
```

Inicialmente teníamos estos grupos

```
final %>% 
    group_by(n_grupo) %>% 
    summarize(n=n()) %>% 
    mutate(n_grupo=as.character(n_grupo)) %>% 
    bind_rows(tibble(n_grupo="Total", n=sum(.$n)))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  grupo     n
  <chr> <int>
1 1        10
2 2         4
3 3         4
4 4         5
5 5         9
6 6        18
7 Total    50
```

y los hemos reorganizado así

```
final %>% 
    group_by(n_grupo) %>% 
    summarize(n=n()) %>% 
    mutate(n_grupo=as.character(n_grupo)) %>% 
    bind_rows(tibble(n_grupo="Total", n=sum(.$n)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  n_grupo     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 1          23
2 6          27
3 Total      50
```