# Cómo usar group_by más un condicional?

Tags: r, condiciones, group-by

Tengo un grupo de datos (aquí una submuestra)

[image: df1]

Los he agrupado usando group_by

```
df2<-df1 %>%
  group_by(rebl, año, mes) %>% 
  summarize(n()) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("ram")
```

De tal manera que ahora tengo

[image: df2]

Como pueden ver, hay algunas combinaciones que tienen n<=10 y tengo que redistribuirlas en otro grupo dentro del mismo año. Por ejemplo

```
ram     rebl          año     mes     n()

3      01020010068    2014    2        9
4      01020010068    2014    3        6
```

La idea sería redistribuir o sumar estos dos ram al grupo

```
ram     rebl          año     mes     n()

2      01020010068    2014    1        12
```

De tal manera que los ram 3 y 4 ya no existan más, y que el ram 2 tenga n=27.

He intentado hacerlo usando

```
 if (df1$n<=10) df1 %>% group_by(rebl, año) %>% summarize(n()) 
else if (df1$n>=10) df1 %>% group_by(rebl, año, mes) %>% summarize(n())
```

Pero me sale el error: "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Cómo podría hacer la redistribución que necesito?

Comment: Vas por el camino correcto @Caro, el reporte que deseas se puede lograr directamente si se cambia `group_by(rebl, año, mes)` por `group_by(rebl, año)`. También quisiera acotar que `library(dplyr)` cuenta con un `filter` por ejemplo `df1 %>% select (rebl, año, mes) %>% filter(año == 2015, mes>6)`, filtra los datos correspondiente al segundo semestre del año 2015.

Comment: No puedo cambiar directamente group_by(rebl, año, mes) por group_by(rebl, año) porque primero tengo que tener en cuenta las 3 variables y luego, basándome en esa primera agrupación, hacer una redistribución de los grupos con menos de 10 obs considerando sólo el rebl y el año. Sería dividir en 2 df (uno con las obs <10 y otro >10) y decir if df1$rebl==df2$rebl & df1$año==df2$año then... Esto ya no sé cómo indicárselo

Comment: Una consulta @Caro en que difiere esta pregunta, de la anterior que realizaste [¿Cómo reagrupo categorías siguiendo una condición?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243363/c%C3%B3mo-reagrupo-categor%C3%ADas-siguiendo-una-condici%C3%B3n)

Comment: @ Hubert, interpreté en tu primera respuesta que me sugerías hacer group_by(rbl, año) desde el principio. Difiere en que se me ha ocurrido partir el df inicial en dos, uno con las obs<10 y otro >10... pero he llegado al mismo punto de no poder llegar a lo que quiero. Seguiré dándole vueltas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consideraciones

Como la consulta es especifica y sólo cuento con los datos parciales para verificar, es decir, la factibilidad de generalizar la solución que se va ha exponer continuación, voy a tomar los datos `df2` para detallar lo resuelto:

```
library(dplyr)
#library(tibble) # no es necesario trabajar en este caso con la funcion: rowid_to_column
library(tidyr)
df2<-data.frame(ram=1:13,
                rebl=c(rep("010020010068",13)),
                año=c(2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017,2017),
                mes=c(12, 1, 2, 3, 11, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                n=c(78,12,9,6,11,9,7,19,14,10,31,19,9)
)
df2

   ram         rebl  año mes  n
1    1 010020010068 2013  12 78
2    2 010020010068 2014   1 12
3    3 010020010068 2014   2  9
4    4 010020010068 2014   3  6
5    5 010020010068 2014  11 11
6    6 010020010068 2015   1  9
7    7 010020010068 2015   2  7
8    8 010020010068 2016   1 19
9    9 010020010068 2016   2 14
10  10 010020010068 2016   3 10
11  11 010020010068 2017   1 31
12  12 010020010068 2017   2 19
13  13 010020010068 2017   3  9
```

### Sobre la  solución

Con los datos provenientes de la primera consulta -*emplee `n` y no `n()` como nombre de columna*- hay que aplicar un filtro para separar `df2`

con `n<=10`:

```
diezMe<-df2 %>% 
        group_by(rebl,año) %>% 
        filter(n<=10, año==first(año)) %>%
        summarise(n=sum(n)) %>% as.data.frame()
diezMe
          rebl  año  n
1 010020010068 2014 15
2 010020010068 2015 16
3 010020010068 2016 10
4 010020010068 2017  9
```

y con `n>10`

```
diezMy<-df2 %>% 
        group_by(rebl, año, mes) %>% 
        filter(n>10) %>%
        summarise(n)%>% as.data.frame()
diezMy
          rebl  año mes  n
1 010020010068 2013  12 78
2 010020010068 2014   1 12
3 010020010068 2014  11 11
4 010020010068 2016   1 19
5 010020010068 2016   2 14
6 010020010068 2017   1 31
7 010020010068 2017   2 19
```

Observar que `diezMe` (*menor o igual a 10*) no contiene la columna `mes` y en realidad no sería relevante porque su columna `n` tiene que ser sumada a `diezMy$mes` pero... aquí hay un caso particular:

> `diezMe` contiene el año `2015`, en cambio `diezMy` carece de él, en tal sentido, remarco, esta solución sólo responde a los datos provistos, en todo caso, habría que ver otras variantes para ir escalando la solución.

Para resolver lo anterior es necesario capturar los primeros meses de cada año (*en el 2018 podría tenerse un caso similar*) y agregárselos a `diezMe` de la siguiente forma:

```
diezMeMes<-aggregate(mes~ rebl+año , df2, FUN=head,1)
diezMe <- diezMe %>%
            mutate(mes=diezMeMes$mes[diezMeMes$año %in% año])%>%
            select(rebl, año, mes, n)
diezMe
          rebl  año mes  n
1 010020010068 2014   1 15
2 010020010068 2015   1 16
3 010020010068 2016   1 10
4 010020010068 2017   1  9
```

Como tiene que haber una suerte de intersección ([inner_right](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp)) entre el **data.frame**: `diezMe` y el `diezMy` el año **2015** -u otros años-, quedaría en el aire, en tal sentido, se procede a su extracción (`fila o filas`) de `diezMe` para una posterior recuperación.

```
recuperar<-diezMe[!(diezMe$año %in%  diezMy$año),]
diezMe<-diezMe[diezMe$año %in%  diezMy$año,]
diezMe
          rebl  año mes  n
1 010020010068 2014   1 15
3 010020010068 2016   1 10
4 010020010068 2017   1  9
```

Bueno, luego comparto un pequeño truco para obtener las posiciones dónde empiezan los años, dada una columna -sin que se repitan-, mediante un vector binario (`cond`):

```
diezMy$dif <- c(1, diezMy$año[-1] - diezMy$año[-length(diezMy$año)]) # siempre empieza en 1
diezMy$cond <- ifelse(diezMy$dif>0,1,0) # se genera un vector (columna) binario
diezMy$añoMod <- diezMy$año*diezMy$cond
diezMy
          rebl  año mes  n dif cond añoMod
1 010020010068 2013  12 78   1    1   2013
2 010020010068 2014   1 12   1    1   2014
3 010020010068 2014  11 11   0    0      0
4 010020010068 2016   1 19   2    1   2016
5 010020010068 2016   2 14   0    0      0
6 010020010068 2017   1 31   1    1   2017
7 010020010068 2017   2 19   0    0      0
```

Las columnas `dif`, `cond` y `añoMod` son básicamente columnas de ayuda y no van en el producto final, dichas columnas también pueden ser obtenidas mediante `mutate`, pero vi conveniente dar el paso a paso en **R** base, para que puedan ser impresas las sentencias respectivas y ver más al detalle su comportamiento.

> **La idea central es obtener años sin repeticiones y sin perder las posiciones donde empiezan**.

Asimismo vale aclarar que la columna binaria `cond` pudo ser:

```
 c(TRUE, FALSE)*c(2013,2104) # se imprime [1] 2013 0
```

> También es bueno acotar qué, la disposición de `añoMod` sólo es válida si se busca agregar las sumas provenientes de `diezMe$n` al primer mes del año respectivo en el data.frame de `diezMy`, porque en este caso particular, los datos presentados permiten asumir eso.

Lo que prosigue es sumar los valores de `diezMe$n` a `diezMy$n` en los años respectivos, para tal fin se crea un vector auxiliar (`np`) ya que la expresión que genera al vector `verif` puede colocarse dentro de `np`, por lo que su construcción (`verif`) es opcional. Aquí el detalle del procedimiento:

```
verif <- diezMy$añoMod %in% diezMe$año
verif
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

np<-(1:length(diezMy$n))*0
np[verif]<-diezMe$n
np
# [1]  0 15  0 10  0  9  0

diezMy$n<-diezMy$n+np
diezMy
          rebl  año mes  n dif cond añoMod
1 010020010068 2013  12 78   1    1   2013
2 010020010068 2014   1 27   1    1   2014
3 010020010068 2014  11 11   0    0      0
4 010020010068 2016   1 29   2    1   2016
5 010020010068 2016   2 14   0    0      0
6 010020010068 2017   1 40   1    1   2017
7 010020010068 2017   2 19   0    0      0
```

### Resultado

Finalmente hay que darle forma al reporte solicitado, sin dejar de incluir la(s) fila(s) almacenada(s) previamente en `recuperar`

```
dfFinal<-diezMy[,1:4]
dfFinal[nrow(dfFinal)+1,]<-recuperar

dfFinal<-dfFinal[order(dfFinalMy$año),]
row.names(dfFinal) <- 1:nrow(dfFinal)

# RESULTADO FINAL
dfFinal
          rebl  año mes  n
1 010020010068 2013  12 78
2 010020010068 2014   1 27
3 010020010068 2014  11 11
4 010020010068 2015   1 16
5 010020010068 2016   1 29
6 010020010068 2016   2 14
7 010020010068 2017   1 40
8 010020010068 2017   2 19
```